# Y-axis flip issue - Matlab App designer GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

Based on this question [Calculate Y coordinates of an image from graph point of origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316875/calculate-y-coordinates-of-an-image-from-graph-point-of-origin?noredirect=1#comment124339526_70316875) I tried to do the same in app designer GUI but it does not work. I attached an image that shows that the image does not start from graph point of origin and that I get a new figure due to the *set* command. Any idea how to fix/do it?

Code:

```
function ButtonPushed(app, event)
    url='https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/thesquid.ink/free-flat-sample/512/owl-icon.png';

    I = imread(url);
    I = rgb2gray(I);
    I=flipud(I);
    
    imshow(I,'Parent', app.imageAxes); 
    set(gca,'YDir','normal')
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gca` creates a new figure window and a new set of axes if there are none. In particular, the app designer window is not a figure window, and so a new one is created.

But you don’t need to use `gca` to get a reference to your axes, since you already have the reference in `app.imageAxes`. This will set your axes to have a normal orientation:

```
set(app.imageAxes, ,'YDir', 'normal')
```

This should be the same as

```
app.imageAxes.YDir = 'normal';
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try to import the image data as a 2-dimensional grid, and then flipping it.. could work not sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).